# When I make input binding to the "return" key in a DataGrid, I don't leave the edit cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, inputbinding

When I am in a grid, I want to capture some keys to do something. I capture the "delete" key and I have not problems, but when I try to capture the "Return" key and I am editing a cell, when I press the Return key I don't leave the edit cell mode.

If I don't do the keybinding of the Return, when I press the return while I am editing a cell, it leaves the edit mode and goes to the next row.

If I comment all the code of the "Return" keybinding, the problem occurs, so I think that the problem is not the code that I use, but is the input keybinding of the return key.

must I have some special considerations when I want to capture the return key?

I am using the following code in the xaml to make the binding:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding myCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="Delete"/>

                <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding myCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="Return"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the existing input-binding to the [`CommitEditCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.commiteditcommand.aspx), you need to manually execute that command in your own if you want to retain the default behavior.

*(You can use [`CommitEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.commitedit.aspx) for that, which invokes the command.)*

Comment: I am using the MVVM pattern, so, how can I execute the CommitEdit command of the DatGrid?

Comment: @Daimroc: Don't know, be creative, maybe split up your command in one for return and one for delete and pass the DataGrid as parameter so you can invoke methods on it.